# Нужна ли запятая перед «что» в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Нужна ли запятая в перед «что» в предложении: «**Даже не знаю что хуже**»?

Answer (score 2):

**Даже не знаю, что хуже!**

Запятая ставится в сложноподчиненном предложении с придаточным изъяснительным.

***ЧТО*** ― союзное слово. Придаточное неполное, его смысл определяется из контекста.

Answer (score 1):

Да, запятая перед *что* необходима — она разделяет две части сложноподчинённого предложения (местоимение "я" опущено).
Чаще всего вторая часть предложения имеет бОльшую "распространенность" (в ней и указываются особенности тяжкого выбора):

***Я даже не знаю, что хуже***: не знать, кто ты и быть счастливым, или стать тем, кем ты всегда хотел быть и чувствовать себя одиноким.
Дэниел Киз. Цветы для Элджернона

***Даже не знаю, что хуже*** – эти казематы или пороховая бочка!
И. Никифоров. Голос разума

*...и **я даже не знаю, что хуже** – смерть здесь, пусть даже и такая жуткая, или жизнь там?*
Е. Звёздная. Шепот в темноте